# simulating packet losses and delays programmatically

Tags: networking, rpc, go, packets

I have a server that exposes its services over rpc and a client that uses these services. To test this setup, I need to introduce packet losses and delays. I found a few techniques on stackoverflow like tc, modifying iptables etc but all of them need root password to simulate the packet loss. Is there a way to simulate these packet losses without needing a root password.

Note: The code is written in GO programming language

Comment: why simulate it when you could just run it over a mobile GSM / 3G network? ;-)

Comment: Unplug the network cable for short periods.

Comment: By the way, I found out recently that this is sometimes referred to as "Fuzzing", and devices and software called "Fuzzers" are available that modify/corrupt network traffic in useful ways. In some cases they're kind-of clever, and create intentionally-almost-correct data, like duplicated packets, or syntactically valid information mixed from old packets, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to isolate your packet handling code, and create mock-version of it (or ifdef'd sections) that, for testing, misbehave in the manner of your choosing.

That may be enough for your needs.

For industrial-strength testing, for a commercial or critical application, you'll want AT LEAST a box where you have root password. :) And perhaps more exotic test equipment that can misbehave in more exotic ways.